# R: write.table include variable names?

Tags: r

I have a datafile(math) and then I created ID variable. I tried to combine them into one datafile WITH all the variable names in 'math' and 'id'.

I keep saving the combined file without variable names. I might have not used read.spss or write.table function properly. What did I miss?

```
math="2009_Math.sav"
m=read.spss(math,use.value.labels=false)
mathid<-c(1:65535)
names(mathid)<-c("id")
mathfile<-data.frame(math,mathid)
write.table(m2009, file="math2009.sav",sep=",",row.names=F,col.names=T,quote=F,append=T)
```

Comment: What's `m2009`? I don't see where you defined it.

Comment: oh, my mistake--instead of m2009 use mathfile. still did not work.

Comment: do i understand it correctly that you are trying to add to your dataframe `m` an id column?

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what you're asking, but I think what you want is:

```
filename <- "2009_Math.sav"
m <- read.spss(filename, use.value.labels=false)
m$id <- 1:nrow(m)
write.table(m, file="math2009.csv",sep=",",row.names=F,col.names=T,quote=F,append=T)
```

Comment: I got this error though> m$id <- 1:nrow(m) Error in 1:nrow(m) : argument of length 0

Comment: @kkk  can you give us the output of `str(m)`

Comment: what is str(m)? which output is it?

Comment: oh, I am sorry here is str(m):

Comment: List of 22
 $ Subject   : chr [1:136322] "M" "M" "M" "M" ...
 $ Grade     : num [1:136322] 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
 $ DistCode  : chr [1:136322] "120455203" "103028653" "112679403" "125237903" ...
 $ SchoolCode: chr   ..$ DOB       : NULL
  ..$ MatchCri1 : NULL
  ..$ MatchCri2 : NULL
  ..$ MatchCri3 : NULL
  ..$ MatchCri4 : NULL
 - attr(*, "codepage")= int 1252

Comment: this is not the the whole lsit because it was too big. I had to cut some in the middle. But ID variable was not created by using m$id<-1:nrow(m)

Comment: Ok I got it. m$id<-nrow(m) should be used instead of 1:nrow(m). then it worked. but why not I can save as sav file instead of csv?